# React Native - Sketch Canvas

Tags: android, ios, canvas, react-native, drawing

There are some components for drawing in ReactNative for IOS and Android like [react-native-sketch-canvas](https://github.com/terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas) but...

¿It's possible start the component with something printed?

For example: When `componentdidmount()`, put some references, and then, the component appears with something drawn.

It will be very useful if you let me some reference

Comment: Use `state`. You show some references first, when you are ready to show `drawns`, change the `state value` and re-render the screen

Comment: @gaback you know any example?

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937498/react-native-change-screen-after-x-seconds` this example shows you how to re-render after `x seconds`